# Animation, Image.Source and bindings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this view model:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        // indeed, images are dynamically generated
        normal = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Normal.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        flash = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Flash.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public bool IsFlashing
    {
        get { return isFlashing; }
        set
        {
            if (isFlashing != value)
            {
                isFlashing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsFlashing");
            }
        }
    }
    private bool isFlashing;

    public ImageSource Normal
    {
        get { return normal; }
        private set
        {
            if (normal != value)
            {
                normal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Normal");
            }
        }
    }
    private ImageSource normal;

    public ImageSource Flash
    {
        get { return flash; }
        set
        {
            if (flash != value)
            {
                flash = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Flash");
            }
        }
    }
    private ImageSource flash;
}
```

I want to animate images in the view (from `Normal` to `Flash` and back again), when `IsFlashing == true`.
To demonstrate, what I'm trying to achieve, I'll post a piece of XAML:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <CheckBox Content="Is flashing" IsChecked="{Binding IsFlashing}"/>

                <Image x:Name="MyImage" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Normal}"/>
            </Grid>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFlashing}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage" 
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" 
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{Binding Normal}"/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{Binding Flash}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

This doesn't work, because animation engine can't freeze storyboard with bindings.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

I can solve this using timer in view model... but this approach smells.

**UPDATE**
According Richard Deeming's answer, data template look this way. It works and it definitely better, than timer:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <CheckBox Content="Is flashing" IsChecked="{Binding IsFlashing}"/>

                <Image x:Name="NormalImage" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Normal}"/>
                <Image x:Name="FlashImage" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Flash}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFlashing}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" 
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" 
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                               Duration="0:0:1">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FlashImage" 
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" 
                                                               RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                               Duration="0:0:1">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalImage" 
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                               Duration="0:0:1">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FlashImage" 
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                               Duration="0:0:1">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to have two overlapping images - one bound to the `Normal` source, and one bound to the `Flash` source. You can then use the `Storyboard` to animate the `Visibility` property on the two images.